# how to define range for p:inputmask

Tags: java, primefaces

i am using primefaces 5.0 , My requirement is

How to Define Range for inputMask . in my case input mask should allow values from 0-12 .

please let me know in case of any Details required .

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $("#input-mask").keydown(function(e) {
                    var key = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
                    if (!((key == 46) || (key == 8))) {
                        if ((key < 48) || (key > 57)) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                        } else {
                            var s = $(this).val();
                            var l = s.length;
                            if((l >= 2) || ((l == 1) && !((s == '1') && (key == 48)))) {
                                event.preventDefault();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
```

i am trying this

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to allow only the numbers for inputMask tag,

You need to specify the `mask` attribute with the regex , `[0-9]{1, 5}` will allow only 0-9 and between 1-5 characters.

```
<p:inputMask mask="[0-9]{1, 5}"/>
```

will do the work without jquery , see [`inputMask`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/5.0/org/primefaces/component/inputmask/InputMask.html) for info .

Comment: He is using 5.0, you point to the 3.4 docs... Not good, please correct

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a [spinner](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/spinner.xhtml)

```
<p:spinner id="minMax" value="#{spinnerView.number3}" min="0" max="12" />
```